# Prove or disprove a claim about sign vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let

$$\mathbf{s}^{1},\dots,\mathbf{s}^{M} \in \{\pm 1\}^{N}$$

be $M$ vectors with $N$ components, whose entries are $+1$ or $-1$ (this is what I mean by "sign vectors"):

$$s_{i}^{m} = \pm 1$$

Any vector can then be expressed as a sum:

$$\mathbf{s}^{\parallel} + \mathbf{s}^{\perp}$$

where

$$\mathbf{s}^{\parallel} = \sum_{m}a_{m}\mathbf{s}^{m}$$

belongs to the linear span of the vectors $\mathbf{s}^{1},\dots,\mathbf{s}^{M}$, while $\mathbf{s}^{\perp}$ is orthogonal to all of them,

$$\mathbf{s}^{\perp} \cdot \mathbf{s}^{m} = 0,\quad m = 1,\dots,M$$

**Claim.** $\mathbf{s}^{\parallel} + \mathbf{s}^{\perp}\in\{\pm 1\}^{N}$, if and only if $\mathbf{s}^{\parallel} - \mathbf{s}^{\perp}\in\{\pm 1\}^{N}$ as well.

I intuitively expect this to be true. I can also verify this statement exhaustively for $N=3$ (essentially by staring at a picture of a 3-dimensional cube). But cannot prove it in general, nor come up with any counter-example. I feel I might be missing something trivial. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is essentially
"if $V$ is the subspace generated by some vertices of the $N$-dimensional cube
centred at $0$, is the cube symmetric about $V$?"

I don't think this is true, even in $3$ dimensions.

For example, consider the line generated by $(1, 1, 1)$ (I'll use row notation
for vectors).

Consider the vector $v = (1, 1, -1)$. This decomposes as
$\tfrac 13(1, 1, 1) + \tfrac 13(2, 2, -4)$
where $(2, 2, -4)$ is obviously orthogonal to this line.

Hence its reflection through the line is
$\tfrac 13(-1, -1, 5)$, which does not lie on the cube.

Indeed, if you draw a line through $(1, 1, -1)$ and $V$ which is perpendicular
to $(1, 1, 1)$, you see it intersects the cube at $(0, 0, 1)$. Here is a
picture:

[image: picture of cube]

The problem is essentially that if you look at cross sections along the line $V$, then the cube
has four "layers" of vertices. The next layer after $(1, 1, 1)$ has three
vertices: $(1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 1)$, and $(-1, 1, 1)$. These are distributed in a
nice equilateral triangle around $V$, so reflecting through $V$ cannot preserve
this triangle.

A case where it is true is when $V$ is trivial. Also, if $N = 2$ and $V$ is a
line it's true, and if $N = 3$ and $V$ is
$2$-dimensional, it's true. This perhaps begs the question "is it always true
when $V$ is $(N - 1)$-dimensional?"

I believe this is still not the case. Consider when $N = 4$ and
$V$ is generated by $v_1 = (1, 1, 1, -1)$, $v_2 = (1, 1, -1, 1)$, $v_3 = (1, -1, 1, 1)$.
The perpendicular vector to $V$ is
$(1, -1, -1, -1)$.

So consider for example $v = (1, 1, 1, 1)$. We have
$v = \tfrac 12(v_1 + v_2 + v_3)  -\tfrac 12(1, -1, -1, -1)$.

So the reflection is $v + (1, -1, -1, -1) = (2, 0, 0, 0)$, which is not on the
cube.

---

In response to your comment - a more general question might simply be
"consider the $N$-dimensional hypercube in $\Bbb R^N$, and some subset
$S$ of $M$ of its vertices. There is a group $G_S$ which is the group of all
isometries of $\Bbb R^N$ that preserve the cube and fix each vertex in $S$. What
does this group look like? Is it always nontrivial when $S$ generates a proper
subspace of $\Bbb R^N$? Does it always contain a nontrivial
orientation-preserving isometry?"

Note that each isometry $\alpha \in G_S$ induces an isometry of the
orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span} S$.

The group $G_\emptyset$ of isometries of the cube is fairly
[well-understood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group)
algebraically. It is actually quite a combinatorial object. A key fact is that
any isometry of the cube sends every standard basis vector $e_i$ to
$\pm e_j$ for some $j$, and in fact any linear automorphism $\alpha$ which sends
each $e_i$ to $\pm e_j$ for some $j$ gives rise to such an isometry.

From this it follows that the group $G_\emptyset$ of isometries of the cube may
be identified with the group of permutations $\pi$ of
$\{-N, \dotsc, -1, 1, \dotsc, N\}$ such that
$\pi(i) = -\pi(-i)$ for all $i$. I will use this identification from now on.

Under this identification, a vertex $x$ of the cube corresponds to
a subset $X$ of $\{-N, \dotsc, -1, 1, \dotsc, N\}$ such that for each $i$,
exactly one of $i$ and $-i$ appears in $X$. A permutation $\pi \in G_\emptyset$
corresponds to an isometry fixing $x$ iff the set $X$ is $\pi$-stable - meaning
that for all $i \in X$, we have $\pi(i) \in X$.

So now the question is - given $M$ such sets $X_1, \dotsc, X_M$, can we think of
a nontrivial such permutation $\pi \in G_\emptyset$ such that
each $X_i$ is $\pi$-stable?

If $M = 1$, then there will be many such $\pi$. The set of $\pi$ such that
$X$ is $\pi$-stable corresponds exactly to the symmetric group on $X$.
So $G_X$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group of order $N!$
(CF: in the example above with the three-dimensional cube, the group of
isometries preserving the line is the group of isometries of a triangle, which
is $D_6 \cong S_3$). In general half of
these isometries will be orientation-preserving (aka, "rotations"),
corresponding to the even permutations. This reasoning gives a nice way to show
that there are $2^N \cdot N!$ isometries of the cube (by the orbit-stabiliser
theorem).

However, in general, it is possible to choose vertices
$S = \{X_1, \dotsc, X_{N - 1}\}$ such that $G_S$ is trivial. This isn't terribly
surprising - in general requiring that $M$ sets are $\pi$-stable implies
that many more sets are $\pi$-stable. In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are
$\pi$-stable, then so are $A \cap B$, $A \cup B$,
$A \setminus B$, $B \setminus A$, $-A = \{-a : a \in A\}$, and sets obtained by
repeated use of all these operations. These
allow us to generate many more constraints on $\pi$. The fact that we can always
find nontrivial $\pi$ in small dimensions is in some sense just due to the lack
of combinatorial "wiggle room".

Here is an example with $N = 6$. Let
\begin{align*}
 X_1 &= \{ 1,  2, -3, -4, -5, -6\} \\
 X_2 &= \{-1,  2,  3, -4, -5, -6\} \\
 X_3 &= \{-1, -2,  3,  4, -5, -6\} \\
 X_4 &= \{-1, -2, -3,  4,  5, -6\} \\
 X_5 &= \{-1, -2, -3, -4,  5,  6\}
\end{align*}
Suppose $\pi$ is such that each $X_i$ is $\pi$-stable.

Then $X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3 \cap X_4 = \{-6\}$ and
$X_2 \cap X_3 \cap X_4 \cap X_5 = \{-1\}$ are $\pi$-stable. Hence
$\pi$ fixes each of $1, -1, 6, -6$.

Now also $X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3 = \{-5, -6\}$ is $\pi$-stable,
and $X_3 \cap X_4 \cap X_5 = \{-1, -2\}$ is $\pi$-stable. Hence
$\pi$ fixes each of $2, -2, 5, -5$.

Lastly, it follows that $X_1 \setminus \{1, 2, -5, -6\} = \{-3, -4\}$
and $X_2 \setminus \{-1, 2, -5, -6\} = \{3, -4\}$ are $\pi$-stable.
Hence $\pi$ must fix $3, -3, 4, -4$, so $\pi$ must be the identity.

(So geometrically, this says that if you take the vertices
$(1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1)$,
$(-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1)$,
$(-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1)$,
$(-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1)$,
$(-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1)$ of the $6$-dimensional cube, then there is no
nontrivial isometry of the cube which fixes these vertices.)

---

I believe it's true that for any fixed $M$, for sufficiently large $N$, for all
sets of $M$ vertices, there is some nontrivial isometry of the $N$-cube fixing
$S$ pointwise.

I'll give a simple argument here - $N$ being at least $2^M$ will suffice.

The key observation is given two vertices (what you call sign vectors)
$u$ and $v$ in $\Bbb R^N$, either $u$ and $v$ or $u$ and $-v$ will match in at
least $N/2$ of their entries. In fact we'll use a slight refinement of this -
for any set $I \subseteq \{1, \dotsc, N\}$, we can choose
$\varepsilon \in \{-1, 1\}$ such that
$|\{i \in I : u_i = \varepsilon v_i\}| \ge |I|/2$.

(This isn't hard to prove - if $u$ and $v$ don't match in $|I|/2$ of their
entries, then $u$ and $-v$ must do.)

So suppose $N \ge 2^M$ and $x_1, \dotsc, x_M$ are vertices of the
$N$-cube. We'll define a sequence of sets
$\{1, \dotsc, N\} = I_0 \supseteq I_1 \supseteq \dotsb \supseteq I_{M - 1}$
and a sequence $\varepsilon_1, \dotsc, \varepsilon_M \in \{-1, 1\}$ such that
$\varepsilon_j x_j$ and $\varepsilon_{j + 1} x_{j + 1}$ have the same entries
for indices in $I_j$, for all
$j = 1, \dotsc, M - 1$, and $|I_{j + 1}| \ge |I_j|/2$. The construction of these
sets is just by repeated application of the fact I observed above.

In particular all of the vectors $\varepsilon_j x_j$ agree on $I_{m - 1}$,
and $|I_{m - 1}| \ge |I_0|/2^{m - 1} \ge 2$. So say $a, b$ are distinct elements
of $I_{m - 1}$. Let
$\delta_a = (\varepsilon_j x_j)_a$ and $\delta_b = (\varepsilon_j x_j)_b$. (for
any $j$ - they're all the same by construction of $a$ and $b$)

Define an isometry $\alpha$ of $\Bbb R^n$ by
$e_a \mapsto \delta_a \delta_b e_b$ and
$e_b \mapsto \delta_a \delta_b e_a$, and $e_k \mapsto e_k$ for all other $k$.

Clearly $\alpha$ preserves the cube and is nontrivial. But also,
$\alpha$ fixes each $\varepsilon_j x_j$, since
$\alpha(\varepsilon_j x_j)_a
  = (\varepsilon_j x_j)_b \delta_a \delta_b = \delta_b^2 \delta_a = \delta_a$
and similarly $\alpha(\varepsilon_j x_j)_b = \delta_b$.

Hence $\alpha$ fixes each $x_j$. So we are done.

(This is quite symbol-heavy. It just says that after possibly replacing some of
the vertices with the opposite vertex, we can assume they all have some entries
in common, and hence they're fixed by the isometry swapping those entries and
adjusting the sign accordingly.)

Comment: Thanks that's a nice counterexample.

Comment: I see now I have to modify my statement, though I'm not sure yet exactly how. The idea is that if $\mathbf{s}^{\parallel} + \mathbf{s}^{\perp}\in\{\pm 1\}^{N}$, then also $\mathbf{s}^{\parallel} + R\mathbf{s}^{\perp}\in\{\pm 1\}^{N}$, where $R$ is some rotation operator. So in your example, one can produce three points by such rotation.

Comment: @a06e, I have edited my answer to add an example where $N = 6$ and $M = 5$, and there are no non-identity $R$ preserving the cube's vertices. This suggests to me that it's hard to modify your statement in a way that generalises nicely to all dimensions, but perhaps you could ask "how small must $M$ be for there to be a nontrivial such $R$"? (I don't know the answer to this.) The theory of high-dimensional cubes becomes much more combinatorial than geometric!

Comment: Thanks again! This is more subtle than I anticipated. Can we at least give a bound for $M$ and $N$? For example, say $N$ is very large, while $M$ stays finite. I would guess the claim holds at least in this case.

Comment: @a06e, I think if $N$ is at least $2^M$ then for any set of $M$ vertices, there's a nontrivial isometry of the cube fixing those vertices. I've given a short explanation in my answer. This is a typical big combinatorics bound (to be honest they can be quite a lot worse than this!). I have no idea how much it can be improved. I think there must be some literature on a problem equivalent to this but I can't seem to find it I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks. I can now compute the number of elements of the hyperoctaedron subgroup that leaves invariant $M$ vertices, I could post it if you are interested. From this formula it's evident the condition you need to have non-trivial transformations. If you happen to find some more literature on this I'd be interested to check it out. Honestly it seems fascinating to me and way richer than I expected.

Comment: @a06e, I'm definitely interested! Please do post that. I agree that it's really interesting stuff.

Comment: I have added an answer with the calculation. Would appreciate it if you took a look in case I made some blunder! Thanks!

Comment: You might find this question interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821408/linear-combinations-on-the-hypercube

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the hyperoctahedral subgroup that leaves the $M$ vertices,

$$\mathbf{s}^{1},\dots,\mathbf{s}^{M} \in \{\pm1\}^{N}$$

invariant. That is, $g(\mathbf s^{m})=\mathbf s^{m}$ whenever $g\in G$.

It is useful to divide the indices $i=1,\dots,N$ into subsets $V$, such that $s_i^{m}=S_V^{m}$ has a common value for all $i\in V$. We also call $V_{-}$ the group of indices with the negative value, $s_i^{m}=-S_V^{m}$ for $i\in V_{-}$. There are $2^{M}$ possible subsets $V$, corresponding to the possible values that the $M$-tuple $(S_V^{1},\dots,S_V^{M})$ can take.

An element $g$ of the hyperoctahedral group is specified by two things: a permutation $p_1,\dots,p_N$ of the axes $1,\dots,N$, and signs $t_1,\dots,t_N = \pm 1$ which correspond to reflections of these axes.

For $g\in G$ we then have from $g(\mathbf s^{m})=\mathbf s^{m}$ the equations:

$$t_{p_i}s_{p_i}^{m}=s_{i}^{m}$$

Multiplying by $s_{p_i}^{m}$,

$$t_{p_i}=s_{i}^{m}s_{p_i}^{m}$$

Suppose $i\in V$, using the sets $V$ introduced above. Then $t_{p_i}=1$ or $t_{p_i}=-1$ according to whether the permutation $p_i$ sends $i$ to $V$ or to $V_{-}$. In any case, we necessarily have $p_i\in V\cup V_{-}$.

How many members does $G$ have? We just have to count how many permutations there are of this form,
$$|G| = \sqrt{\prod_V (|V|+|V_{-}|)!}$$
where the product over $V$ goes over all the possible $\pm 1$ $M$-tuples. The square root is needed because each pair $V,V_{-}$ appears twice.

In particular, if $|V|+|V_{-}|\le1$ for all $M$-tuples, $|G|=1$ must be a trivial group, containing only the identity. In this case, there is no non-trivial hyperoctahedral transformation of the hypercube that leaves the chosen $M$ vertices invariant.

If $N > 2^{M}$, the pigeonhole principle forbids that $|V|+|V_{-}|\le1$ for all $M$-tuples, and therefore in this case $|G|>1$ is non-trivial (in agreement with the sufficient condition given in Izaak van Dongen answer).

Comment: Hello. Apologies for the delay. This looks absolutely right to me. Nicely done! I feel silly for not realising that $G$ must act in this way on the "rows" of the vertices. I think it follows from this that $N \ge 2^{M - 1} + 1$ is also sufficient, and in fact my argument above also shows that. In general I think it's not too hard to think of $M$ vertices in the case $N = 2^{M - 1}$ with no nontrivial isometry - take $s^M = (1, 1, \dotsc, 1)$ and also take the vectors $s^m$ where $s^m_n$ is $-1$ iff the $m$th bit of $n-1$ in binary is $1$.

Comment: So really this question is related very closely (up to worrying about multiplication by $-1$) to the question of "how few subsets of a set do you need so that every element of the set is the unique element in the intersection of some of those subsets", which is basically about binary encodings.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and for all your comments, it's been really interesting.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen BTW if you happen to find any interesting related literature please mention it here. Thanks!