# Vector spaces and hypercube vertices

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

The following statement is taken from Kanter & Sompolinsky (1987). It is stated without a complete proof.

Let $\xi_{i}^{\mu}=\pm1$ be $p$ spin vectors chosen uniformly at random in $N$ dimensions. Thus the indices $\mu=1,\dots,p$, and $i=1,\dots,N$. Let $\mathcal{V}_{p}$ denote the linear subspace spanned by these $p$ vectors. What is the probability that $\mathcal{V}$ contains another spin vector $\in\{\pm 1\}^{N}$, different from the $p$ vectors $\{\xi_{i}^{\mu}\}$ and their negatives?

Kanter & Sompolinsky (1987) claim that this probability vanishes like:
$$P(p) \sim 4\binom{p}{3} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{N}$$
as $N\to\infty$, for all $p/N < 1 - 7\ln(2)/\ln(N)$. They cite an unpublished paper (see references below), and give the following sketch of an argument:

> The origin of the result (2.18) is the fact that the dominant contribution to $P$ comes from the probability of linear combinations of three of the patterns. In order that $\{\xi_i^1,\xi_i^2,\xi_i^3\}$ span another $(\pm 1)$ vector the $N$ triplets $(\xi_i^1,\xi_i^2,\xi_i^3)$ must contain only six out of the eight different triplets, yielding the result (2.18).

But I can't reconstruct a full proof. Any suggestions?

**References:**

- Kanter, I., and Haim Sompolinsky. "Associative recall of memory without errors." Physical Review A 35.1 (1987): 380.
- A. Odlyzko (unpublished).